# Open view with slide effect from bottom to top on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, slide

I'm making an application for iPhone (which runs in landscape mode) (OS 3.0), and I want that when I touch a toolbar button it opens a view with a slide effect (similar to the effect when you touch 'Bookmarks' in Mobile Safari's toolbar) from the bottom to the top of the screen. The view is in the same XIB file as the button.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:yourSlideController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are asking about doing the animation custom here's a snippet that might help.
Lets assume the view "myView" is already added as a subview to the current view.

```
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480)];
[myView setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[myView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

The important numbers in there are the y positions in the setFrame rect (480 then 0), this moves it from offscreen to onscreen.

Comment: It is working best for more applying SlideView as in iphone facebook app more option.