# Objective-c Hidden View animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, hidden

Hello I have a hidden view inside of my view that appears by the click of a button. But when you click on the button I want the view to do an slide up animation so it won't just appear but slide up to it's position.

Here is the code for my hidden view:
in .h:

```
@interface hidden_viewsViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIView *loginview;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *loginview;

- (IBAction)login;
- (IBAction)logout;
```

And in .m

```
@synthesize loginview;

- (IBAction)login {

    loginview.hidden = NO;

}

- (IBAction)logout {

    loginview.hidden = YES;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    loginview.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open view with slide effect from bottom to top on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312366/open-view-with-slide-effect-from-bottom-to-top-on-iphone)

Comment: yes me also +1 for duplicate, your link answers exactly this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try, assuming the view is in portrait orientation:

```
- (IBAction)login {
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:loginView];
    loginview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480); 
    loginview.hidden = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                     animations:^{
                         loginview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
                     }];
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it goes "under" the first view so all buttons etc from the first view is still displayed in the view that animated up. How would I fix that?

Comment: By calling `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:loginView];`, added it to the solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

you should change the frame property of your view, and you should do it within an animations block, as follows:

```
-(IBAction)login
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"showView" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    CGRect viewNewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewNewFrame.origin.y = 0;
    self.view.frame = viewNewFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
 }
```

Hope it helps!